# factory pattern using repository in DDD

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, factory-pattern

I have object Project in domain as below

```
public class Project implements Entity<Project> {
    private ProjectId projectId;
    private ProjectTitle projectTitle;
    private ProjectDescription projectDescription;
    private ProjectStatus projectStatus;
    private ProjectNumberOfMember projectNumberOfMember;
    private ProjectDate startDate;
    private ProjectDate endDate;
    private Owner owner;
    private ProjectLgcDelFlag lgcDelFlag;
    private Admin admin;
}
```

Owner and admin object get from table onwer and admin in DB.
And here Project Entity to mapping table DB (I using JPA)

```
    public class ProjectEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 255)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "number_of_member")
    private int numberOfMember;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private long startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private long endDate;

    @Column(name = "owner_id")
    private long ownerId;

    @Column(name = "lgc_del_flag")
    private int lgcDelFlag;

    @Column(name = "admin_id")
    private long adminId;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private long createdBy;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private long createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private long updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private long updatedAt;
}
```

I using class ProjectFactory to mapping ProjectEntity , so in DDD allow inject repository to get info of Admin and Owner from DB ?

Comment: DDD ist just a methodology or concept there is are no strict implementation rules.

Answer (score 0):

In DDD a rule of thumb is that an aggregate references another one by the id of the aggregate root entity, so in the Project entity of the domain you shouldn't have Owner, but OwnerId. Same for Admin.

So in the Project factory, you don't need to get info from Owner or Admin, you just need their ids in order to construct a Project object.